# Safari на iPad игнорирует символы фута и дюйма при кастомном шрифте

Tags: css, ipad, шрифты, safari

Safari на iPad не отображает символы фута (`′` = `\u2032`) и дюйма (`″` = `\u2032`) при использовании шрифта [Anago](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/positype/anago/).

Насколько я понимаю, в этом шрифте нет нужного символа, но десктопные браузеры отображают недостающие символы стандартным шрифтом. На iPad ситуация другая.

При этом я попробовал другие отсутствующие в шрифте символы (заменил латинские `ace` на кириллические `асе`), и они отобразились корректно дефаултным шрифтом.

Так в чём же проблема с данными двумя символами?
**Как сделать, чтобы эти символы отобразились стандартным шрифтом?**

```html
<!doctype html>

<meta charset=utf-8>

<title>iOS Safari doesn't render feet and inches</title>

<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: "Anago";
  src: url("Positype - Anago-Book.otf");
  font-weight: 300;
}

body {
  font-family: Anago, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 4em;
}
</style>

<p>Just a test - latin</p>
<p>Just а tеst - lаtin аnd сyrilliс</p>
<p>5′ 9.7″</p>
<p style="font-family: sans-serif">5′ 9.7″</p>
```

Десктопный Chrome в Windows:

[image: Скриншот с хрома]

Десктопный Safari на Mac:

[image: Скриншот с сафари]

Safari на iPad:

[image: Скриншот с айпада]

Другие браузеры на iPad'е ведут себя аналогично.

PS: [Этот вопрос по-английски.](//stackoverflow.com/q/40228339/4928642)

Comment: Маловероятно, но мало ли: что, если попробовать вместо самого символа использовать подстановку `&Prime;`?

Comment: @MaratTanalin, не помогло.

Comment: Воспроизводится ли проблема с другими шрифтами, где отсутствует тот же самый символ? Это помогло бы локализовать источник проблемы: некорректный шрифт или баг браузера.

Comment: @MaratTanalin, если использовать `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">` и шрифт Pacifico вместо Anago, то проблема НЕ воспроизводится.

Comment: @MaratTanalin, ой.. А похоже, в гуглошрифте этот диапазон есть...

Answer (score 0):

В самом начале вашего CSS-файла добавьте следующую строку:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

Comment: Эм.. Я проверю, но: 1. Там тег `style`, а не css-файл. 2. Почему кодировка css-файла влияет на применение шрифтов к html?